# howto set ogr2ogr imported SRID to 0? Currently defaulting to SRID 1

Tags: ogr2ogr, mysql, epsg, srid

I'm currently trying to import a bunch of boundaries into a legacy system with a specific `SRID`. its a `mySQL` db.

After import and running some intersect code, i receive this error:

```
Binary geometry function st_intersects given two geometries of different srids: 1 and 0, which should have been identical.
```

As it says, there is an `srid` mismatch of `1` vs `0`. The newly imported boundaries are `SRID 1`, the existing boundaries from another table (cannot be changed) are `SRID 0`. I have established this with mysql command

```
select ST_SRID(boundary_polygon) from boundaries;
```

My question, what `EPSG` value would i use with `ogr2ogr`'s `-a_srs` flag. I want to force SRID=0?

Here is the current command i'm using for import:

```
ogr2ogr -f "MYSQL" MYSQL:"blahdb,host=localhost,user=blah,password=blah,port=3306" boundaries.tab
```

I'm currently running this command which forces the import to `SRID=0` which seems by convention to mean No SRID.

```
UPDATE boundaries SET boundary_polygon = GeomFromWKB(boundary_polygon, 0);
```

This then allowed my st_intersects method to work fine and find intersect between two polygons.

However, I still need a way to import as SRID=0 from ogr2ogr instead of SRID=1. So that I don't need this post import SQL step

Comment: You can try to add `-a_srs EPSG:0` into your ogr2ogr command but I fear that it fails.

Comment: @user30184 no when i try with EPSG:0 i get error, `ERROR 1: Failed to lookup UOM CODE 0`

Comment: GDAL driver page gives only this information: `SRS information is stored using the OGC Simple Features for SQL layout, with geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys metadata tables being created in the specified database if they do not already exist. The spatial_ref_sys table is not pre-populated with SRS and EPSG values like PostGIS. If no EPSG code is found for a given table, the MAX(SRID) value will be used.` I would check what spatial_ref_sys contains. Perhaps you can fiddle the MAX(SRID) into "0",

Comment: Interesting, when i select from `spatial_ref_sys` it indeed only has a single record with SRID = 1. I assume if I change this value, it will default to 0 from then on?

Comment: @user30184 yep ok, so manipulating the `spatial_ref_sys` allowed changing default to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior with SRIDs in the GDAL MySQL driver is not very clearly explained on the driver manual page http://www.gdal.org/drv_mysql.html. A hint can be found from the "Caveats" section

> SRS information is stored using the OGC Simple Features for SQL
>   layout, with geometry_columns and spatial_ref_sys metadata tables
>   being created in the specified database if they do not already exist.
>   The spatial_ref_sys table is not pre-populated with SRS and EPSG
>   values like PostGIS. If no EPSG code is found for a given table, the
>   MAX(SRID) value will be used.

What probably happens when you save data into MySQL for the first time with an unknown SRID is that GDAL does not find the **spatial_ref_sys** metadata table. Because the table does not exist it is created and one row with SRID=1 is inserted. Next time the metadata table exists and value MAX(SRID)=1 will be used when new data with unknown projection are saved into new tables.

A workaround, kindly tested by user @wired00, is to make one conversion with some dummy data with GDAL so that **spatial_ref_sys** table appears and update the SRID from 1 to 0. Now MAX(SRID)=0 and zero will be used as SRID in following conversions.

Comment: Yes that's right by merely editing the single srid row in `spacial_ref_sys` from 1 to 0 it would auto default to that projection.